# show two lines in one SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, select

I have those three tables in my DataBase called Equipe (teams), Match(Match), Jouer (Played), and I'm trying to show the result of the league using this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.ID_MATCH, NOM_EQUIPE, BUT_MARQUE
FROM EQUIPE AS E, JOUER AS J, [MATCH] AS M
WHERE E.ID_EQUIPE = J.ID_EQUIPE and J.ID_MATCH = M.ID_MATCH
ORDER BY M.ID_MATCH;
```

and the table is like this:

EQUIPE:

[image]

Match:

[image]

and they are related with the tabble JOUER :

[image]

the problem is that I'm getting the result like this:

[image]

Is there any way to show the result more like

```
 ID_MATCH , Team1 , result1 , Team2 , result2
```

Comment: What's mean  `Team1 , result1 , Team2 , result2` on your tables schema?

Comment: in the result you can see that i have the same ID_MATCH for two teams and wat i want to do is to turn the two lines int one @daniel.shih

Comment: Either CROSSTAB query http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html or VBA http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: I think since it's only two teams (in a match) a crosstab is not necessary. The interesting schema doesn't enforce that but I think the real world reality does (for the OP to confirm). Unfortunately, the schema makes the SQL more complicated than it could be though. It would be better if a match contained references to the two teams and columns for their respective scores.

Comment: I have a solution here for you.  It should give you exactly what you want - but I'm hoping you can give it a test drive since I don't have the data to test it on myself.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try This:

```
SELECT M.ID_MATCH, E1.NOM_EQUIPE, J1.BUT_MARQUE, E2.NOM_EQUIPE, J2.BUT_MARQUE
FROM JOUER AS J1
INNER JOIN JOUER AS J2 ON J2.ID_MATCH = J1.ID_MATCH and J2.ID_EQUIPE > J1.ID_EQUIPE 
INNER JOIN [MATCH] AS M ON J1.ID_MATCH = M.ID_MATCH
INNER JOIN EQUIPE AS E1 ON E1.ID_EQUIPE = J1.ID_EQUIPE
INNER JOIN EQUIPE AS E2 ON E2.ID_EQUIPE = J2.ID_EQUIPE
ORDER BY M.ID_MATCH;
```

The trick is in joining JOUER to itself on ID_MATCH but also only when J2.ID_EQUIPE > J1.ID_EQUIPE.  That way you only get 1 combination of teams instead of 4.

I hope this helps.  Bonne Chance!

Comment: @NidalEl - It parses cleanly on my end.  What database are you using?

Comment: @NidalEl - Had you copied the text much earlier?  When I first posted this, I was missing one of the 'ON's for a couple of minutes.  I caught it (and fixed it) almost immediately because I proof-read it just after posting.  But if you copied it in that state, it would give you some kind of syntax/parsing error.

Comment: @NidalEl - Have you seen this solution since my last update - it works on my end.  Please remember to 'Accept' this as the answer if it helps you.  Merci!